# Change logging format of SpringBoot - micrometer to JSON

Tags: json, spring-boot, logging, spring-micrometer

I have a SpringBoot application that uses micrometer to print out application metrics.

My pom.xml has:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

My Config class is:

```
@Configuration
public class CoreConfiguration {

    public static final String USER_REQUEST_CHANNEL = "userRequestChannel";
    public static final String USER_RESPONSE_CHANNEL = "userResponseChannel";
    public static final String MDC_ADD = "add";
    public static final String DONE_CHANNEL = "nullChannel";
    public static final String ADMIN_REQUEST_CHANNEL = "adminRequestChannel";
    public static final String ADMIN_RESPONSE_CHANNEL = "adminResponseChannel";
    public static final String SUPPORT_COMPLETED_CHANNEL = "supportCompletedChannel";
    public static final String SUPPORT_RUNNING_CHANNEL = "nullChannel";
    public static final String SUPPORT_ERROR_CHANNEL = "nullChannel";

    @Bean(name = USER_REQUEST_CHANNEL)
    public MessageChannel oAuthRequestChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean(name = USER_RESPONSE_CHANNEL)
    public MessageChannel oAuthResponseChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean(name = FIRST_TRADE_CHANNEL)
    public MessageChannel firstTradeChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean(name = ADMIN_REQUEST_CHANNEL)
    public MessageChannel instructionExecutionRequestChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean(name = ADMIN_RESPONSE_CHANNEL)
    public MessageChannel instructionExecutionResponseChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean(name = SUPPORT_COMPLETED_CHANNEL)
    public MessageChannel groupExecutionCompletedChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    /**
     * Turn on the Micrometer log file metrics.
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public LoggingMeterRegistry loggingMeterRegistry(@Value("${micrometer.log.minutes}") long minutes) {
        LoggingRegistryConfig config = new LoggingRegistryConfig() {
            @Override
            public String get(String s) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Duration step() {
                return Duration.ofMinutes(minutes);
            }
        };
        return LoggingMeterRegistry.builder(config).build();
    }
}
```

**USAGE IN CLASS:**

```
public IntegrationFlow processRequest(HttpRequest request) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(INPUT_CHANNEL)
            .enrichHeader(m -> m.headerExpression(REQUEST_ID,"payload.message.headers." + REQUEST_ID))
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG, CoreConfiguration.class.getName(), m -> {
                Throwable t = (Throwable) m.getPayload();
                return throwableToString(t);})
            .get();
}
```

I see the output of the metrics written to my log file as:

> 2019-02-25 14:40:23,337 | INFO  | [logging-metrics-publisher] |
>   [meter.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry] | MY_SAMPLE_APP |
>   userId = [] | jvm.memory.max{area=heap,id=PS Survivor Space}
>   value=12.5 MiB

**How do I log out in JSON format?**

**WHAT I NEED:**

```
{
"ts": "2019-02-25 14:40:23,337" ,
"level" : "INFO",
"className" : "meter.core.instrument.logging.LoggingMeterRegistry",
"appName" : "MY_SAMPLE_APP",
"userId" : "",
"metric" : 
        {"metricType": "jvm.memory.max",
         "area":"heap",
         "id":"PS Survivor Space",
         "value":"12.5 MiB"
         }
}
```

Updating question with code as per Jon's answer.
@Jon, do you think the below code is correct? I have implemented a custom Meter Registry that extends the LoggingMeterRegistry.

The only difference between LoggingMeterRegistry and CustomMeterRegistry is that my custom class print out ID=

**In LoggingMeterRegistry:** `this.loggingSink.accept(print.id() + " throughput=" + print.rate(count));`

**In CustomMeterRegistry:** `this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " throughput=" + print.rate(count));`

**COMPLETE CODE:**

```
public abstract class SplunkMeterRegistry extends LoggingMeterRegistry {
@Override
protected void publish() {
{
    if (this.config.enabled()) {
        this.getMeters().stream().sorted((m1, m2) -> {
            int typeComp = m1.getId().getType().compareTo(m2.getId().getType());
            return typeComp == 0 ? m1.getId().getName().compareTo(m2.getId().getName()) : typeComp;
        }).forEach((m) -> {
            LoggingMeterRegistry.Printer print = new LoggingMeterRegistry.Printer(m);
            m.use((gauge) -> {
                this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " value=" + print.value(gauge.value()));
            }, (counter) -> {
                double count = counter.count();
                if (this.config.logInactive() || count != 0.0D) {
                    this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " throughput=" + print.rate(count));
                }
            }, (timer) -> {
                HistogramSnapshot snapshot = timer.takeSnapshot();
                long count = snapshot.count();
                if (this.config.logInactive() || count != 0L) {
                    this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " throughput=" + print.unitlessRate((double)count) + " mean=" + print.time(snapshot.mean(this.getBaseTimeUnit())) + " max=" + print.time(snapshot.max(this.getBaseTimeUnit())));
                }
            }, (summary) -> {
                HistogramSnapshot snapshot = summary.takeSnapshot();
                long count = snapshot.count();
                if (this.config.logInactive() || count != 0L) {
                    this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " throughput=" + print.unitlessRate((double)count) + " mean=" + print.value(snapshot.mean()) + " max=" + print.value(snapshot.max()));
                }
            }, (longTaskTimer) -> {
                int activeTasks = longTaskTimer.activeTasks();
                if (this.config.logInactive() || activeTasks != 0) {
                    this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " active=" + print.value((double)activeTasks) + " duration=" + print.time(longTaskTimer.duration(this.getBaseTimeUnit())));
                }
            }, (timeGauge) -> {
                double value = timeGauge.value(this.getBaseTimeUnit());
                if (this.config.logInactive() || value != 0.0D) {
                    this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " value=" + print.time(value));
                }
            }, (counter) -> {
                double count = counter.count();
                if (this.config.logInactive() || count != 0.0D) {
                    this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " throughput=" + print.rate(count));
                }
            }, (timer) -> {
                double count = timer.count();
                if (this.config.logInactive() || count != 0.0D) {
                    this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + " throughput=" + print.rate(count) + " mean=" + print.time(timer.mean(this.getBaseTimeUnit())));
                }
            }, (meter) -> {
                this.loggingSink.accept("ID=" + print.id() + StreamSupport.stream(meter.measure().spliterator(), false).map((ms) -> {
                    return ms.getStatistic().getTagValueRepresentation() + "=" + DoubleFormat.decimalOrNan(ms.getValue());
                }));
            });
        });
    }

}
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear to me how that results in the JSON payload you originally asked for. Regardless, I see now that what you really want is a Splunk implementation. Perhaps we should consider first-class support for that?

Comment: @jkschneider, thankyou for your response. I need to finish the code in 2 -3 days. Can you please help me write a custom MeterRegistry that outputs in JSON format by providing me some example code?

Comment: Most of the push based registries write JSON. See `DatadogMeterRegistry`, `InfluxMeterRegistry`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You must implement a custom `MeterRegistry`, perhaps using `LoggingMeterRegistry` as a reference, that serializes the data in the format you desire. Effectively that's what push-based `MeterRegistry` implementations are is just different serialization formats for different consumers.